# Spring 3.2.4 Servlet Configuration Error -- Controller not catching URL

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I'm trying to refactor an app that is currently using a CXFServlet to use a dispatcher servlet for REST api requests.

I created a servlet and servlet mapping in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I then created a api-servlet.xml with:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.myapp.api"></context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Finally I created a new controller in the appropriate package:

```
@Controller("eventsController")
@RequestMapping("/api/events")
public class EventsController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogUtils.getLogger();

    @GET
    @Path("/{eventId}")
    public EventDto getEvent(@PathParam("eventId") Long eventId) {
        //do controller stuff
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public List<EventDto> getEvents() {
        //do controller stuff
    }
}
```

The app starts up fine, I the servlet is initialized and the eventsController bean is found and I get no errors. On trying to hit the rest endpoint though, I get a error:

```
Apr 17, 2015 11:02:27 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/events/42] in DispatcherServlet with name 'api'
```

I've looked through several other posts with this error and haven't found a solution yet.

Thank you.

Comment: can you share the full URL of the request?

Comment: I think your `@RequestMapping` should be `("/events")`  since your Servlet already is mapped to `/api`

Comment: Thank you for that advice -- I actually originally had the mapping as /events and have tried it both ways with the same error resulting, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally figured this out -- the @GET and @Path annotations were correct for the CFXServlet implementation but NOT for vanilla Spring, I needed to change the annotation to @RequestMapping(value="/{eventId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)  and then everything worked. I also ended up changing the controller annotation to @RestController, but it worked just fine with the previous annotations.